# FBDialog still in beta for iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

Are we able to use FBDialogs in production apps yet? Looking at the latest SDK 3.5.3 I see this: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/FBSettings.h#L58

Which states that we shouldn't be using the native fast app switching share dialog in app store apps yet. Can someone clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They're in production, meaning that you don't need to set those flags anymore.